# Get dependencies to build package from source

Tags: linux, bash, mplayer, opensource-projects

I had an interview task to build an opensource software from source. One of the tasks was to come up with the dependencies (and tools) that were needed to build from source. However, I am working off a distribution with a lot of packages that I have previously installed. I only needed to install one extra tool to build the software.

My question is, how do you know what prerequisites were needed to build the software.

Extra:
In case this help (you are curious), the software to build was `mplayer 1.2.1`. I only needed to install `yasm`. I was building this on `arch-linux`.

I have already submitted my response. Feel free to give explicit answers with a clean conscience!

My batch file was:

```
## build.sh ##

#! /usr/bin/env bash

set -e

wget http://www.mplayerhq.hu/MPlayer/releases/MPlayer-1.2.1.tar.xz

tar -xvf MPlayer-1.2.1.tar.xz

cd MPlayer-1.2.1


./configure
./configure --enable-gui

make
```

Answer (score 1):

To determine dependencies of a project, (assuming it's a dynamically linked compiled binary), you can run `ldd` on the compiled results. This will show you exactly which libraries are required to build (but not necessarily all)  and run the software.